# move_uploaded_file not replacing the old image

Tags: php, php-ini

i have a problem.I have a form to change the user profile image. if the user has no previous images, the php works fine, the image is uploaded, if the file exists, the move_uploaded_file is not replacing the image, and it does work on my localhost, but not in my online server. THis is my code

```
if ($_POST['parse_var'] == "pic"){

// If a file is posted with the form
if ($_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'] != "") { 
        $maxfilesize = 4109212; 

        if($_FILES['fileField']['size'] > $maxfilesize ) { 
                    $error_msg = '<font color="#FF0000">ERROR: Your image was too large, please try again.</font>';
                    unlink($_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name']); 

        } else if (!preg_match("/\.(gif|jpg|png|jpeg)$/i", $_FILES['fileField']['name'] ) ) {
                    $error_msg = '<font color="#FF0000">ERROR: Your image was not one of the accepted formats, please try again.</font>';
                    unlink($_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name']); 
        } else { 
                    $newname = "profile.jpg";
                    $place_file = move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'], "users/$id/".$newname);
        }
    } 
}
```

Any ideas why? it works the first time the users changes it, it can be a PHP .ini problem?
The file uploads correctly the first time, once you have uploaded an image it doesnt work any more, its like you cant replace the image inside the folder

Comment: There's no point of `unlink()` as temporary files will be deleted by PHP on script execution termination.

Comment: what's inside $place_file?

Comment: file getting uploaded?

Comment: The file uploads correctly the first time, once you have uploaded an image it doesnt work any more, its like you cant replace the image inside the folder

Answer (score 0):

You can start here:

- **Trace the error**: Add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` below `$maxfilesize = 4109212;`
- **Double check folder location**: `users/$id/filename` means that you are sending this image to a folder called *users* which is located where your script file is running. Maybe you could use absolute paths instead. Also, is the $id variable already set?

Comment: If you have a look, OP says that the execution works the first time. Which means that `move_uploaded_file()` is failing a 2nd time because the image already exists. OP needs to unlink original file before attempting to write new file.